# Why is this showing two different result is chrome and mozilla browser

Tags: html, css

I was practising html css and made a nav, but the result is different in chrome and Mozilla browser. i want the service and portfolio at the top and other menus at bottom. i have given down class padding top and its working fine in chrome but in mozilla all the menus are aligned in straight line. Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="down"><a href="#FIXME" title="About"><img src="assets/images/about.png" alt="About"></a></li>
                        <li class="down"><a href="#FIXME" title="Team"><img src="assets/images/team.png" alt="Team"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#FIXME" title="Services"><img src="assets/images/service.png" alt="Services"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#FIXME" title="Portfolio"><img src="assets/images/port.png" alt="Portfolio"></a></li>
                        <li class="down"><a href="#FIXME" title="Blog"><img src="assets/images/blog.png" alt="Blog"></a></li>
                        <li class="down"><a href="#FIXME" title="Contact"><img src="assets/images/contact.png" alt="contact"></a></li>
                    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code

```
nav {
padding-top: 9%;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.down {
    padding-top: 60%;
}

nav li {
    width: 15%;
}
```

link to codepen: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/gopalrathore94/pen/WpQvOM)

Comment: Care to be more specific about the problem, e.g. what exactly the difference is between the browsers?

Comment: @MadGab i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<ul>` element has no specified height on the flex container, so the % vertical padding is resolving to 0 in Firefox. Add a height and it should work. Alternately, you could change your padding in the `.down` class from a percentage to px.

```css
nav {
    padding-top: 9%;
 
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 500px;
}

.down {
    padding-top: 10%;
}

nav li {
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="down">
            <a href="#FIXME" title="About"><img src="assets/images/about.png" alt="About"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="down">
            <a href="#FIXME" title="Team"><img src="assets/images/team.png" alt="Team"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#FIXME" title="Services"><img src="assets/images/service.png" alt="Services"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#FIXME" title="Portfolio"><img src="assets/images/port.png" alt="Portfolio"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="down">
            <a href="#FIXME" title="Blog"><img src="assets/images/blog.png" alt="Blog"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="down">
            <a href="#FIXME" title="Contact"><img src="assets/images/contact.png" alt="contact"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Also, take a look here [w3c docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins)

> Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers.

Comment: but dont want the middle two images of the bottom ul..can you suggest a method using one ul?

Comment: My real question is why mozilla is behaving like this? why cant it be like in chrome?

Comment: @Gopal Singh Rathore Thank you for clarifying. I’ve updated my answer. Maybe Chrome just doesn’t worry about the spec that covers this, while Firefox does.

Comment: I have added some info about compatibility issues. Great answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Just test your browser compatibility for HTML5. https://html5test.com/index.html